# Xamarin.Forms (Shared)

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I was asked to investigate if our iOS app could be replaced with cross platform technology like Xamarin.

I off went to give it a try and I found some OK tutorials. However, I don't seem to be able to even get past the install of Xamarin.

I use VS2015 I installed everything that was listed by Xamarin installer. I get a list of Xamarin projects but when I create any of them I'm showing 100s of errors with missing references etc. that I can't get rid off. I installed all the SDKs for Android studio but no luck with compiling a basic out of the box plain Xamarin.forms application.

Any insight would be appreciated,

Thank you,
Radek

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     error: cannot find symbol   public
>   Toolbar_NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher
>   (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar p0) throws java.lang.Throwable
>   symbol:   class Toolbar   location: package
>   android.support.v7.widget XamarinForms.Droid  c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\XamarinForms\XamarinForms\XamarinForms.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\android\support\v7\widget\Toolbar_NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher.java  27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DELETE "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" FOLDER FROM LOCATION

```
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Xamarin
```

After try to rebuild your project.

Comment: I didn't have that folder in this location, deleted all the obj and bin folders from the project file including packages folder from project directory, when re-builded,  I got the Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat folder showing in local\Xamarin but no files inside and getting the same error, I'm assuming if I can find how to get files in these folders that would probably solve it, not sure where to get them though

Comment: Got it working, I deleted everything again, restarted Visual Studio and it compiled, go figure. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Delete your obj and bin folders from your solutions -  after that clean & rebuild.

Comment: Tried that as per my comments above, but no luck

Comment: Got it working, I deleted everything again, restarted Visual Studio and it compiled, go figure. Thank you very much